# 404 error on running the project on Mac OSX

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, tomcat, tomcat7

On Mac. 
I was trying to run a spring project but could not run because of the following reasons: 
Tomcat server has been started but myproject is not getting deployed on the tomcat server.
The default localhost:8080 is accessible and opens up the default apache page but myproject is not deployed on tomcat.

I tried several ways but could not arrive at the solution. could some one please help me out.I did switch location and changed in serverlocations to the second option that is "use tomcat installation"

Just to make sure I even tried to run a default dynamic webproject, the hello world application.But this was also not deployed on the tomcat server and was throwing 404 error.

The same project I was able to run on windows with out any problem.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you deploy your project?

Comment: I have just added the server as tomcat from eclipse --> preferences --> add server, and give the necessary fields like location of tomcat and jre etc and then i right click on the project from project explorer and run on server

Comment: please share the exception from console here when starting the server.

Answer (score 1):

After selecting your project 
Double click on the server tab from bottom and select “Use Tomcat installation (take control of Tomcat installation)”

It should now work perfectly.

Comment: Which version of tomcat are you using?